# Pause a while loop and not the rest of my program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, while-loop, sleep

I'm making a (simple) program in Python, where I push a button to make a ball drop, and then the ball automatically goes up again, on a slower rate. The ball drop part works, but I can't seem to make the going up part happen.

My first instinct said using an if. But the if only triggers once, and I want it to trigger every time the ball drops. I couldn't seem to make that work.

My second though was using a while loop. But, I can't seem to get the right timing in the loop. I can't trigger it outside my button, so now I trigger it inside it. Like this:

```
def callback1():
    global l1
    w.move(cirkel1, 0, 20)
    label1.configure(text=l1)
    while l1 != 0:
        w.move(cirkel1, 0, -20)
        l1 -= 1
```

But the while loop executes at the exact same time I press the button, which makes that the ball doesn't move at all. I tried looking around and found a sleep function, but that has the problem that it pauses my whole program, not just the loop. And I want to be able to lower the ball even further while it is going up slowly. I tried looking for a timer or something like that, but I couldn't find anything understandable and that looked like working.

Am I doing something wrong, forgetting an option or is what I want simply not possible? Please help me.

Comment: What are `w` & `label1`?

Comment: I am using a GIU with tkinter. Label1 is the first label I use (so where the text gets displayed) and I use it to keep a count of the amount of times the buttom gets pressed, or how 'low' the ball is. w is from the canvas I use, and makes the oval I drawed move down.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the threading module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

You can for example embed all your animation inside a thread's `run()` method.
You can also use `Timer` objects for the consecutive steps of the animation.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough in Python, I don't really understand how exactly to include this information in my code, to make it work.

Comment: What is cirkel1? How is called function callback1() ?